# While installation using laravel 5.4 with PHP 5.6

Tags: laravel

**I'm Facing this problem, while installation using laravel 5.4 with PHP 7**

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.5.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.

```
- phpunit/phpunit 5.5.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.5.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.5.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.5.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.5.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.4.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.3.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.3.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.3.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.3.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.3.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.3.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.12 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.11 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.10 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.2.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.1.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.1.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.1.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.1.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.1.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.1.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.1.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.1.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.10 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 5.0.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.

- Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ~5.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5].
```

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:

```
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
```

You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Answer (score 0):

**To Fix this problem, i have made some installation:**

**sudo apt-get install yum** (You need to install php dom extension) 
Still the problem not yet fixed, do this **sudo apt-get install php-xml**

Comment: If this is the answer, tag this question with linux.

Comment: If you're on a system that uses APT, like Ubuntu, you shouldn't need to install YUM (Which is a package manager for Redhat/CentOS style distributions). Simply installing the required PHP modules should suffice.